# Animation in menu

Tags: android, android-animation, android-menu

I'm trying to display an animation in place of a simple png on the android menu:

I have an animation in drawable/gif.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false" android:visibility="true">
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif0" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif1l" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif2l" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif3l" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif2la" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif1la" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif0" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif1r" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif2r" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif3r" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif2ra" android:duration="1000" />
        <item android:drawable="@mipmap/notif1ra" android:duration="1000" />
    </animation-list>
</animation-list>
```

And my oncreateoptionsmenu is something this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
menu.findItem(R.id.notifications).setIcon(R.drawable.gif);
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) menu.findItem(R.id.notifications).getIcon();
frameAnimation.start();
return true;
    }
```

But it doesn't display anything...In fact it leaves the place for the icon on the menu, but it doesn't dislay the animation or even one of the png (like if the animation was invisible but not gone).

I took example on this: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Does someone have an idea?
Thank you!